# Multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main method with something like:

```
A a = new A();
a.start();

B b = new B();
b.start();
```

B works on file that a.start creates so a.start() has to finish first.However,
a.start() runs a multi-threaded job and before it's done b.start() is executed.

1. How come the main thread that starts a.start() exits the method before it's done?
2. What's a good way to make sure b.start() does not start before a.start() is done?

Thank you!

Comment: It comes because the JVM decides which thread to execute and you can't predict it. Join and concurrent utils are the best way as it has been pointed out below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you don't need to perform these tasks in separate threads at all, but if you really want to you could do something like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.start();
a.join(); // Will wait until thread A is done

B b = new B();
b.start();
b.join(); // Will wait until thread B is done
```

Assuming that A and B are subclasses of Thread, which is discouraged in favor of implementing Runnable and using new Thread(Runnable).start().

A better way to do this would be to use an Executor and have A and B implement Runnable (not extend Thread). Like this:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ex.execute(new A());
ex.execute(new B());
```

A and B will now execute sequentially on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use threads directly, go for the higher level [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) library